# Hold function in geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to implement a **hold function**: a function that holds the value at a previous peak for a specific amount of time.

I would like to mitigate the change of a parameter with this. By default this parameter is very volatile and I want to hold its value at the local maximum of the, say, last 2 seconds. It means that it will be able to grow, but the decrising phase will be mitigated for a while.

I need to use this function in the **Geometry node**. Unfortunatley in the Geometry nodes I'm not aware of any buffer node which I can use to store the local maximum for a specific number of frames.

I tried to use the Random Value node because I believed that it will change it's value only if it gets a new Seed and store its previous value until the Seed is changed. But unfortunately it is updated if any of its inputs are changed. (I set the Min/Max to the variable I wanted to store, and it keeps changing).

*Do you have any ideas? Thank you!*

Comment: You may want to have a look at Simulation nodes https://youtu.be/0p_Rds5w01U

Comment: or at least tell us which Blender version you are using...

Comment: ATM GN only has one state so this isn't really possible

Comment: Andris would a [rolling average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) be acceptable? Easier, I think.. @Gorgious.. we have sorting, and we have the Simulation branch of GN, (or the buffer-hack,) , so maybe it would be possible to stash values on proxy geo. from frame to frame?

Comment: @RobinBetts yes, you're right ! It's just I'm a bit hesitant to advise people to go that route because Simulation Nodes and the buffer hack are an alpha product and, well, a hack :) Honestly I would either wait for an officially supported way to store & retrieve arbitrary data using GN or try out established solutions like Sverchok, Animation Nodes. It might even be solvable with a relatively simple python script. But the question is a little bit too open-ended, could you add a bit more info about your actual setup, OP ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm quite new with Blender. Saw a video or two about the buffer-hack but with limited knowledge I was not able to digest. Instead I wrote a Python script where I was able to store values through different frames in global variables. Global variables don't smell good from my previous studies but at least it works.